# How to add custom loader gif to Ionic V5

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native

I am using latest version of Ionic v5.0.0 and I am trying to add a custom gif loader in my component. I have tried adding background image url and assigning a fixed height and width. But no css properties are taking effect for some odd reason.

Here is my ts code:

```
 const loader = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
    spinner: null,
    cssClass: 'global-loader',
    duration:10000
  });
```

And Here is my home-results component css:

```
.global-loader {

    background: url("/assets/img/loader.gif") no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    --height: 64px;
--max-height: 64px;
--max-width:64px;
--min-height:64px;
--min-width:64px;
--width:64px;
}
```

Still the result is same:
[image]

Any help will be appreciated
Ahmar

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53128132/i-want-to-create-a-custom-loader-in-ionic-4-but-in-the-message-feild-it-is-show

Comment: No it doesn't work the code i am using is kind or similar but css isn't taking effect

Answer (score 0):

Add Your .global-loader css class in global.css file in your project src folder